Combine similiar dropdown options in laravel yet slightly different
The dropdown option is created from a user input, and that's why the options is not consistent but i want to keep it that way(using input) as it's about working positions and it is too wide if we used dropdown. I have used pluck() which is a built-in function in laravel but it won't help me with it as the options is not entirely the same. For example : '3D MODELLER' and '3D MODELER'. how do i solve this?
This is how i retrieve my data in controller
$profileCareers = ProfileCareer::with([
            'userAlumni' => function ($query) {
                $query->select('id', 'username');
            },
        ])
        ->select('useralumni_id', 'position') // Adjust column names as needed
        ->get();

This is how i display it
<input type="text" id="filter-by-career" list="careers" class="w-full p-2 border rounded text-sm" placeholder="Select career">
        <datalist id="careers">
            <option value="All">
            @foreach($profileCareers->unique('position')->sortBy('position') as $career)
                <option value="{{ $career->position }}">
            @endforeach
        </datalist>

I tried to approximate string matching algorithms like Levenshtein distance to detect similar strings but i don't know how to start. Can i know all the possible solutions to this?

Well I am not that familiar with Levenshtein distance algorithm, however isn't it possible to replace the input with something like select2? Where you could dynamicly load options based on the typed in string? So pretty much as soon as the user starts to write 3D MODEL it should already give him the option to select that and that existing value and it should minimize these "duplications". You could also make it impossible to submit the form it it is off just by one character. And if there isn't an option it would allow him to submit the text he typed in. Ofc this is not 100%
